# Save or collect tweets in which I clicked a link

Tags: twitter

I am using Twitter mostly to discover content on the web, so every time I use it I tend to clink on lots of links. I then read through the websites and some I save for myself, some I put on the blog, some source tweets I favourite etc.

I would like to be able to automatically save/collect all the tweets in which I clicked the link. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to archive your favorite links may be to use the Favorite a tweet option. You will see the Favorite link on the Twitter site when you hover over a Tweet. Twitter clients like Hootsuite also support the Favorite option and provide a facility to view all your "favorited" Tweets.

[Links shared on Twitter.com will automatically be shortened to a http://t.co link](https://support.twitter.com/articles/109623-about-twitter-s-link-service-http-t-co). Twitter currently doesn't provide a way to track the history of t.co links or click statistics. If you want a way to track links you followed from Twitter automatically, you may have to bake your own solution, [possibly a bookmarklet](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2012/04/google-mobilizer-bookmarklet-view-just.html) that can use your own redirection and tracking service to look for t.co links.

If you're interested in tracking not just your Twitter link history but all the links you visit, you can make use of [Google Web History](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-let-google-watch-over-your-web.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mac, you can use IFTTT recipe to save your favorited tweets to Dropbox, which is then read by [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus/). A script extracts the links from the tweets and saves then for future reference. Whole "how to": [Send Favorite Tweets To OmniFocus’ Inbox](http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/send-favorite-tweets-to-omnifocus-inbox/).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that https://thinkup.com/ only stores the clicked messages. This stores twitter messages in a database that YOU control.